# Dynamic and Specific Email Designation in Flow

Tags: flow

I have a gotten a flow to working to a point.

The flow does everything I need except send the email to the appropriate individual(s).

The following returned 2 items out of 800+ from the 'MemberQualificationList'. I do not currently have a 'connection' to the 'MemberList', where the email addresses for all are located.

I have a 'Compose 30 Day' (addDays(utcNow(),30, 'MM/dd/yyyy')

I have a variable that contains a string of the four 'Qualfifications' that need to be included.

I have a Get items to the 'MemberQualificationList' / Filter: DueDate equ 'Outputs (Compose 30 Days).

Apply to each / value / 'MemberQualificationList'

Send an email (V2)

To: my email (for test purposes)

Subject:....

Body:....

What I need is to be able to populate the 'To:' field in the 'Send an email' with the email address of the Member whose qualification is expiring (as determined by the Flow) and the Member's supervisor.

I have a MemberList that has the Member's profile and the supervisor's profile, and both email addresses.

How do I use the 'Get items' and its filter, that is finding all the items with 30 days remaining prior to expiration, to also find the Member and Supervisor's email on the 'MemberList' to populate the email 'To:'?

Comment: Could you provide sample data to work with? What is the linking field/column between MemberQualificationList and MemberList? Does [Getitems] filter for MemberQualificationList look like ````[Expiration]=Today()-30````?

Comment: The Linking field between the MemberList and MemberQuailificationList is the 'MemberUniqueID'. Each Member (and Supervisor) has there own 'MemberUniqueID'. Also,  each Member and Supervisor share the same 'LocationAlphaCode' on the MemberList. I already have the email addresses in a field of the MemberList titled 'NotificationEmails'. I need to be able to reference the 'NotificationEmails' column by way of the MemberUniqueIID and place the contents through the Flow in the 'To:' of the Send  an Email.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me. Please provide sample/fictitious data for these lists to understand it better.

Comment: How about this....I have a MemberList. The List has several columns including one titled 'NotificationEmails'. Whenever an item on the List is modified I want the individual to whom that item belongs and their supervisor sent an email. Both the Member and Member Supervisor emails are found in the MemberList 'NotificationEmails' column of the Member affected. How do I ensure the Flow sends emails ONLY to the addresses in the MemberList / NotificationEmails / based on the Member to whom the modification occured?